# Ruby on Rails behavior I do not understand when executing common commands like bundle, rake, and gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been troubleshooting the Ruby on Rails development environment on the workstation I have been recently assigned, and I have observed repeatedly that after executing routine commands, like bundle install or gem install, or rake commands like rake db:migrate, that file and folder permissions related to the gem I am working on are changed to owner:group root and permission 600. These changes could be on the gem file, or its associated files and directories, like .gemspec files and cache files, pretty much anywhere in the gem installation directory.

I only know this has happened when I proceed to my next command, which will fail due to file permissions. I then have to seek out the modified permissions and change them back to 755, and change owner:group back to the web server (in my case, apache.)

I wonder if the user who configured the environment was using root privileges? Could that be a factor? Or is there another reason for this behavior that I am not aware of? More importantly, can I change it?

Thank you for your time.

Edit: If I might, may I ask a different but related question? Scanning the relevant directories for Ruby, Rails, and gems, I find that the file owner could be my server, or it could be root. What SHOULD it be?

Thank you again for reading my question.

---

Update

The situation has not improved - any time I perform bundle or rake commands on my Rails application I can plan on repeating the exercise of finding all the files with permissions changed from 755 to 700. I still have not observed a pattern of which files get changed. A colleague has suggested that there is a Puppet process that is interfering with permissions, so that is something I may research further.
As far as ownership, I have found that the Apache server should own the directory structure, and I have created a separate user specifically for Rails deployment and management. None of my directories or files are owned by root any longer.

Comment: Are you running any of these commands with `sudo`? If so, don't.

Comment: More likely is that their ruby version was installed with sudo I think

Comment: Or their project was made with `sudo` ... (?)

Comment: I do find it necessary to use sudo more often than I think is right. Since I did not perform the original installations, I am only guessing right now. But if this is the case, how can I correct it?

Comment: "how can I correct it" - this is slightly outside of scope of a short answer. :) the gist: install user-level ruby with a ruby version manager (RVM, rbenv, chruby), then reinstall/reconfigure your project.

Comment: I was hoping that a common profile or something similar existed somewhere in the execution chain that governs the setting of file permissions when modifying files and directories. Optimistically, I thought I might find that file, make the necessary edits, and pouf - magic wand. I can dream, can't I? (smile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this old question after 2 years of experience.
After all this time, I find the update script in my /bin folder that explicitly sets file access permissions after executing rake:precompile, which clearly indicates that the precompile command does not explicitly set the proper permissions.
I could have avoided my confusion at the time by simply running the script instead of running the individual tasks. Live and learn.